# Scala/Jerkson: how to deserialize into generic type

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

I'm trying to do something like this with Jerkson:

```
parse[Collection[OrderResource]](orderCollectionJson)
```

It keeps telling me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A, so I guess that's the type erasure deleting my "OrderResource" from the collection.

If I subclass into something like

```
case class OrderCollection(...) extends Collection[OrderResource]
```

I can do:

```
parse[OrderCollection](orderCollectionJson)
```

But that's nasty, as I'd had to create a new subtype for every type of collection. On the other hand, doing

```
parse[List[Foo]](aListOfFooAsJson)
```

seems to work. So why can Jerkson deserialize into the generic List, but not into my own generic type?

Is there any implicit/manifest magic I can use to deserialize my generic collection?

Comment: Is `Collection` the Java interface or your own class?

Comment: It's my own type. Representing a collection of Orders in a HyperMedia way to be specific. It's been a while since I worked in this, but as far as I remember it's just a simple case class wrapping around a List of Orders.

Comment: Jackson now has a native Scala module that should do what you want: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jerkson [special cases](https://github.com/codahale/jerkson/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/codahale/jerkson/deser/SeqDeserializer.scala) sequences.